# How to make ".load()" ignore certain scripts?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am fading an image in on $(window).Load(), and it works lovely, except that when you have social sharing on, the social network scripts sometimes have problems and take over 10 seconds to load, which means the image doesn't fadeIn until the scripts load!

Is there a way to make the following ignore the social scripts?

```
$(window).load(function() {
   images.fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Social scripts being loaded are the ones needed to show the "share" buttons, and they include Facebook, Twitter, Pinterest, StumbleUpon and Google+. Just a few seconds ago the "pinterest" script was stuck loading and the code to load it does have "async" on, so I don't know what else I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options for you:

### 1 - Don't wait for window.load

Rather than waiting for window load, you could look for image load instead. For instance, using this script below the images in the HTML (or using jQuery's `ready` event):

```
(function() {
    var imgs = $("selector for the images you care about");
    var done = false;

    // Hook both load and error events on the images    
    imgs.on("load error", check);

    // We may well have missed some, so do a proactive check
    check();

    function check() {
        var count = 0;
        if (!done) {
            imgs.each(function() {
                if (this.complete) {
                    ++count;
                }
            });
            if (count === imgs.length) {
                done = true;
                imgs.off("load error");
                // Do your effect
            }
        }
    }
})();
```

Note that we don't rely on getting the `load` event, because it may have already fired before we hooked it. So we do an initial check in case we missed all of the load events, and then check again when we see `load` or `error` from any of the relevant images.

### 2 - Load the relevant scripts asynchronously

Rather than using `<script>` tags in your markup, add the scripts you don't want to wait for by appending `script` elements to the DOM. Scripts added in this way are loaded asynchronously and don't hold up the `window.load` event.

E.g.:

```
(function() {
    var scripts = [
        "http://example.com/some/script.js",
        "http://example.com/some/another_script.js",
        "http://example.com/some/script3.js"
    };
    var index, script;
    var parent = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0].parentNode;

    for (index = 0; index < scripts.length; ++index) {
        script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src = scripts[index];
        parent.appendChild(script);
    }
})();
```

Comment: @Cristy: If the `img` element is in the DOM with its `src` set *before* we hook the event (as it will be if we put the code hooking the event at the end of the HTML or in a `ready` handler), it's possible for the event to fire before we hook it. It's a race condition. If would could hook the event *before* the `src` was set, then we could rely on getting the event, but to do that we'd have to add all the `img` elements manually rather than doing it with markup.